# GRANT IDENTIFIED BY vs SET PASSWORD FOR

Tags: mysql

Are these two sets of mysql commands equivalent?:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO remoteuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SomePASSWORD';
```

and

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO remoteuser@'%';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'remoteuser'@'%' = PASSWORD('SomePASSWORD');
```

(for example, does the first maintain a password specific to mydb).

Comment: not exactly. with the second option, there's a small interval between the two queries where the account is wide open as it has no password.